# How to Replace new line character to "||" in workflow variable: string1?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I am building a SharePoint Designer Workflow and I have a following requirement:

workflow variable:

```
string1=line1<br>
line2<br>
line3
```

Required Output:

workflow variable:

```
string1=line1||line2||line3
```

How can I replace a new line character with "||" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sharepoint 2013 designer workflows you can use the "Replace Substring in String" action. To replace a line break you do not need to use any special characters like < br > or 'n like in some programming languages. Simply use the line break in the string builder.
[image: designer screenshot]

Comment: Wow....!!! that worked..!!!

Comment: my solution: (worse)

Comment: convert string to dictionary then replace \u000d\u000a character with ||. Then I will get me desired output i.e. string1=line1||line2||line3